# Find all paths from a node to leaves

Tags: python, network-programming, networkx

I have a huge networkx graph object (1.8M nodes). I want to input this object with a given node and retrieve all paths going from this node to a leaf (a node connected with only one edge). By the way, the length of those paths is not fixed.

The only way I found doing that is:

```
    leaves = [node for node in G.nodes() if len(G.edges(node)) == 1]
    for leaf in leaves:
        paths =  [x for x in nx.all_simple_paths(G, 1, leaf, cutoff=None)]
```

However, it takes ages to loop over all possible leave and look for a path between the given node and the leaf.

Is there a way to get the result faster? Like in ontologies explosion used on information retrieval with ElasticSearch?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add an edge from every leaf to a new node `auxiliary`.  Find all paths from the given node to `auxiliary`.  Then remove the final step of each path and you have all paths from the given node to a leaf.

Comment: SImply brillant.